# Spanish special characters like á ó while displaying shows jumbled or garbage value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, encoding, character-encoding

I have a Spanish validation message which I'm trying to display using my JavaScript.
And all the special characters like above gets changed into & #243;.
And it is only happening when I'm using JavaScript, there are couple of more validation messages in Spanish which I'm displaying through server side and they are fine.

errorString = "<%:Validation.xyz %>";

I'm trying to get from resource file.

Can some one think of quick work around?

Comment: What framework are you using that uses the `<% %>` notation?

Comment: framework 4 and using ASP.NET MVC 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you call *garbage* is actually but the HTML encoded value of the corresponding character and is there to prevent you from XSS. The encoding happens because you are using `<%:` which automatically HTML encodes the string but this shouldn't be a problem for your javascript. Example:

```
var text = 'hello &#243';
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = text;
```

works just fine and displays `hello ó` in the corresponding DOM element.

Comment: SO if the text is currently displayed on the screen then what is foo?

Comment: Thnx, I got it, FOo is nothing but the label on which I need to display the text message to.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you saved your file with UTF-8 encoding (just in case). It happens that it goes into TFS without UTF8 BOM and then mess can happen on client side.

Comment: In Notepad++, I selected the Encoding menu, and sure enough, the encoding was set to ANSI instead of UTF-8.  Once set to UTF-8, I was good to go!  Thanks!

Comment: Great! this was really usefull to me!