# Dropdown menu option for Spanish

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a option dropdown menu with spanish for the selection:

```
<select style="width: 280px" id="Mobility" name="Mobility">
  <option selected=""> Please Select</option>
  <option value=AI> Adl#$*&she - Camboyan</option>
  <option value=AN>As#$#)*&^ - Indio </option>
</select>
```

It will display a drop-down list:

- Please Select
- Asiático - Camboyan
- Asiático - Indio

When I use javascript to replace the a value like

```
var select= document.getElementById( "myOption" );

for( i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++ ){

if ( select.options[ i ].value == "AI" ){

select.options[i].text = "Isle&xF1;o Pac&xED;fico, Guame#xF1;o";
```

Then text of this value value is like** Isle&xF1;o Pac&xED;fico, Guame#xF1;o

instead of display this:

Isleño Pacífico, Guameño

I think when it changed the text, it is just replaced the text in the option but the browser does not encode the entire HTML code. Is there anyway to resolve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398773/spanish-special-characters-like-%C3%A1-%C3%B3-while-displaying-shows-jumbled-or-garbage-va This answer might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Unicode with codepoint values.

try replacing your select.options... code with this,

```
select.options[i].text = "Isle\u00F1o Pac\u00EDfico, Guame\u00F1o";
```

Also a quick search on google returned this link which may help with other characters.

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Answer (score 0):

K

I use this code for other languages too. Therefore, I used this method, it works fine. First, I have to empty the list.

Thanks,

$("#Options").empty().append("");

$("#Options").append("1 - EDD (WIA-1)");

$("#Options").append("2 - TANF/AFCD");

$("#Options").append("3 - CalWORKs");

$("#Options").append("4 - Trong tình trạng phục hồi sức khỏe");

$("#Options").append("5 - Đang theo học trung học K-12");

$("#Options").append("6 - Công nhân bị sa thãi");